# How to use JunitTest in Spring MVC

Tags: junit

I want code a `Junit` for my project but i have a problem below.

This is Junit Test with function loginTest

```
@Test
public void loginTest(){
    User u = userService.login("User", "123");
    assertNull(u);
}
```

And it throws the error:

```
//error tunnel:
java.lang.NullPointerException...
```

Comment: Please provide some more details about the userService, the error you are getting and what you are trying to do here in general